# How to connect acs Acr1255u-j1 to xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nfc

I am doing a project with the acr1255u-j1 and Xamarin forms , but I can't figure how to connect the device to the application .
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Providing a link or some reference to the mystery device you're asking about would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Hello @Jason, here is the link for the product 

https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/403/acr1255u-j1-acs-secure-bluetooth%C2%AE-nfc-reader/

Comment: well, it's a Bluetooth device so using Bluetooth to connect seems like a good first step.  There are numerous posts, articles, tutorials, and libraries available about using Bluetooth devices.

Comment: When i try to connect with Bluetooth is says :  An app is needed to use this device,
and doesn't let me pair it

Comment: Have you read the docs?  Have you contacted the manufacturer?  There is an SDK available, have you researched that?

Comment: i have read the docs, contacted the manufacturer but no response , i have seen the sdk but is 199$ but non left in stock so we bought the device thru amazon  without the sdk